# SQL WHERE query on date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, reporting-services, where-clause

In my table I have 118 records detailing projects. The 2 fields I am concerned with here are startdate and enddate.

I need to produce a report from this view which shows which projects were 'active' between the following date ranges:

01/01/2011 - 01/12/2011

I have tried the following WHERE clase:

```
WHERE startdate BETWEEN '01/04/2011' AND '01/12/2011' 
OR enddate BETWEEN '01/04/2011' AND '01/12/2011'
OR startdate <= '01/04/2011' AND enddate >= '01/12/2011'
```

What comes through does not seem correct, there are only a few records displayed and many which I know for a fact should be displayed are not, such as one project with a start date of 20/07/2011 and enddate of 21/11/2011 dissapears when the WHERE query is run.

Can anyone see a fault with this WHERE query

[image]

Comment: Silly question, but what is the data type for the startdate and enddate?

Comment: used VARCHAR to convert the format to text:

convert(VARCHAR,dbo.tbl_project_data.startdate, 103) AS startdate, 
convert(VARCHAR,dbo.tbl_project_data.enddate, 103) AS enddate,

Comment: What is the underlying data type in the table? Not what you've converted it to, the base type?  `SELECT ISC.TABLE_SCHEMA, ISC.TABLE_NAME, ISC.COLUMN_NAME, ISC.DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ISC WHERE ISC.column_name IN ('startdate', 'enddate')`

Comment: Keep in mind SQL stores time as part of the date, so if you use GetDate() or similar to populate the field values, there is a time portion as well.  1/12/2011 is considered midnight Jan 12, 2011.  If a date field was populated using Getdate() on Jan 12 at 10:00am, it will not appear within the query.

Comment: i dont know but it was in this format:

2008-01-02 00:00:00.000

Comment: @SQL_Surfer, I asked a very similar thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346585/sql-logic-problem-cross-apply-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original query was working, the database I was connecting to however had different date formats to my query.

Answer (score 5):

```
WHERE
    startdate <= '2011-12-01'
AND enddate   >= '2011-01-01'
```

(Assuming the value in enddate is the last date the project is active)

Examples using numbers, searching for anything that overlaps 100 to 200...

```
Start | End | Start <= 200 | End >= 100

 000  | 099 |  Yes         | No
 101  | 199 |  Yes         | Yes     (HIT!)
 201  | 299 |  No          | Yes
 000  | 150 |  Yes         | Yes     (HIT!)
 150  | 300 |  Yes         | Yes     (HIT!)
 000  | 300 |  Yes         | Yes     (HIT!)
```

This absolutely needs an AND in the logic :)

In terms of your query...

Your query with parenthesis, looks like this...

```
WHERE
  (
     startdate BETWEEN '01/04/2011' AND '01/12/2011'
  OR enddate   BETWEEN '01/04/2011' AND '01/12/2011'
  OR startdate <= '01/04/2011'
  )
  AND enddate >= '01/12/2011'
```

But your example never meets the last AND condition.  Try adding parenthesis to be more explicit...

```
WHERE
     (startdate BETWEEN '01/04/2011' AND '01/12/2011')
  OR (enddate   BETWEEN '01/04/2011' AND '01/12/2011')
  OR (startdate <= '01/04/2011' AND enddate >= '01/12/2011')
```

Comment: There are projects that have started in 2009 and are due to end in 2013

Comment: I would also go with this since SQL Server always works with this format and is the international standard.

Comment: @SQL_Surfer - My first example works for those as well.  There are 6 basic scenarios (all prior to your range) (overlapping your range start) (all within your range) (overlapping the range end) (all after your range) (overlapping the whole range).  The two line check works for all 6 of these scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Before the query add

```
set dateformat dmy
```

Also maybe add some brackets

```
WHERE 
(startdate BETWEEN '01/01/2011' AND '01/12/2011')
OR 
(enddate BETWEEN '01/01/2011' AND '01/12/2011')
OR 
(startdate <= '01/01/2011' AND enddate >= '01/12/2011')
```

Comment: I get over 600 records when I do this of completely different data

Comment: Sorry this is in UK format 01/01/2011 means 1st Jan 11 and 01/12/2011 means 1st Dec 11

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `startdate` and `enddate` are date fields,

Try this:

```
WITH Dates AS ( 
      SELECT [Date] = @StartDate
      UNION ALL SELECT [Date] = DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
      FROM Dates WHERE [Date] <= DATEADD(DAY, -1, @EndDate)
) 
-- YOUR SELECT STATEMENT
-- YOUR FROM STATEMENT
CROSS APPLY Dates
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN startdate AND enddate 
-- The rest of your where statement here
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Declaring your start date as `01/01/2011` and your end date as `01/12/2011`

Answer (score 0):

Everyone's looking at this the wrong way round comparing startdate and enddate to a string when you can compare the string to the columns; the following is the simplest way of ascertaining what you want:

```
where ( '01/04/2011' between startdate and enddate
          or  '01/12/2011' between startdate and enddate
         )
```